# combine 3 queries to one, SELECT / COUNT / INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sql-insert

I need help to optimize my 3 queries into one.

I have 2 tables, the first has a list of image processing servers I use, so different servers can handle different simultaneous job loads at a time, so I have a field called **quota** as seen below.

First table name, "**img_processing_servers**"

```
| id | server_url  | server_key | server_quota |
|  1 | examp.uu.co | X0X1X2XX3X |      5       |
|  2 | examp2.uu.co| X0X1X2YX3X |      3       |
```

The second table registers if there is a job being performed at this moment on the server

Second table, "**img_servers_lock**"

```
| id | lock_server  |      timestamp      |
|  1 |       1      | 2020-04-30 12:08:09 |
|  2 |       1      | 2020-04-30 12:08:09 |
|  3 |       1      | 2020-04-30 12:08:09 |
|  4 |       2      | 2020-04-30 12:08:09 |
|  5 |       2      | 2020-04-30 12:08:09 |
|  6 |       2      | 2020-04-30 12:08:09 |
```

Basically what I want to achieve is that my image servers don't go past the max quota and crash, so the 3 queries I would like to combine are:

Select at least one server available that hasn't reached it's quota and then insert a lock record for it.

```
SELECT * FROM `img_processing_servers` WHERE 

SELECT COUNT(timestamp) FROM `img_servers_lock` WHERE `lock_server` = id 

! if the count is < than quota, go ahead and register use

INSERT INTO `img_servers_lock`(`lock_server`, `timestamp`) VALUES (id_of_available_server, now())
```

How would I go about creating this single query?

My goal is to keep my image servers safe from overload.

Answer (score 1):

Join the two tables and put that into an `INSERT` query.

```
INSERT INTO img_servers_lock(lock_server, timestamp)
SELECT s.id, NOW()
FROM img_processing_servers s
LEFT JOIN img_servers_lock l ON l.lock_server = s.id
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING IFNULL(COUNT(l.id), 0) < s.server_quota
ORDER BY s.server_quota - IFNULL(COUNT(l.id), 0) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The `ORDER BY` clause makes it select the server with the most available quota.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for your answer, I shall give it a try, certainly way out of my Mysql coding skills.

Comment: I think I might be having a MySql bug as I get an error message: Column 's.server_quota' in having clause is unknown, I'm 100% sure it's there...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I encountered just a small addition that was giving me a bug and it was that the **s.server_quota** had to be added to GROUP BY for it to work in the HAVING

```
INSERT INTO img_servers_lock(lock_server, timestamp)
SELECT s.id, NOW()
FROM alpr_servers s
LEFT JOIN img_servers_lock l ON l.lock_server = s.id
GROUP BY s.id, s.server_quota
HAVING IFNULL(COUNT(l.id), 0) < s.server_quota
ORDER BY s.server_quota - IFNULL(COUNT(l.id), 0) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Thanks again Barmar!